# Swift - iOS - Create a Newsfeed TableView from Multiple Data Sources/Other TableViewController Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'd like to create a newsfeed/timeline style TableView that pulls in other entries that users have made in various TableView controllers in my app.

#### Current functionality:

Here is the current functionality of the app: users navigate to different categories and add list items in TableViews: [TableView Controller Set Up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYczg.png)

#### Needed functionality:

What I'd like to do is create a new TableViewController that aggregates all of these entries, according to the order of their timestamp. The Timeline TableViewController that the entries are displayed in should pull in the entry title that the user has already entered previously into the TableViewCell: [Newsfeed/Timeline TableViewController.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzE0D.png)

#### Code:

I can get one category of the app (aka one other TableViewController) to feed into my Newsfeed/Timeline view, but not multiple sources. I think the last bit of code is the only place I need to change... The code should somehow conditionally determine which view controller the entry is coming from and assign the appropriate title to the cell.titleLabel.text. Is this possible?

Code for setting up data source for TableView for Timeline/Newsfeed:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return oranges.count + blueberries.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TimelineTableViewCell"
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TimelineTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TimelineTableViewCell.")
        
    }
    
    // Fetches the appropriate fruit for the data source layout.
    let orange = oranges[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = orange.orangeName
    let blueberries = blueberries[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = blueberries.blueberries.name
    return cell
```

Updated code after implementing inheritance (4.11.18) - Table View Controller comes up blank
:
**TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER:**

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class TimelineTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//MARK: Properties

var fruits = [Fruit]()
var fruitList = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TimelineTableViewCell"
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TimelineTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TimelineTableViewCell.")
    }
    
    
    // Fetches the appropriate entry for the data source layout.
    
    let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = fruit.name
    return cell
    

 }
}
```

**ORANGE CLASS:**

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class Orange: Fruit {

//MARK: Properties

override var name: String {
        set {
            super.name = ""
        }
        get {
            return super.name
        }
    }

var size: String
var color: String

//MARK: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("fruits")

//MARK: Types
struct PropertyKey {
    static let size = "size"
    static let color = "color"
    let name = "name"
}

//MARK: Initialization
init? (name: String, size: String, color: String) {
    
    
    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.size = size
    self.color = color

    super.init(name: name)

}
//MARK: NSCoding
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(size, forKey: PropertyKey.size)
    aCoder.encode(color, forKey: PropertyKey.color)
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    
    // The name is required. If we cannot decode a date string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
        os_log("Unable to decode the name for object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    
    // The size is required. If we cannot decode a time string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let size = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.size) as? String else {
        os_log("Unable to decode the size for object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
        
    }
    
    // The color is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
    guard let color = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.color) as? String else {
        os_log("Unable to decode the color for object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    
    
    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, size: size, color: color)
    
 }
}
```

Comment: Instead create an array: fruit array, that combine oranges and blueberries in the order you want. Then, you can check what's the class of the object at index `indexPath.row` (orange or blueberry). What you can also do is use a protocol that they will both follow and use it, or make them inherits from the same class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Would you be able to share some sample code to demonstrate your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The orange and blueberry should inherits from the Fruit class, and the model will be an array of fruit. Your code can be something like this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruit.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TimelineTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TimelineTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TimelineTableViewCell.")
    }
    // Fetches the appropriate fruit for the data source layout.
    let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = fruits.name
    return cell
}
```

To setup fruit - orange and blueberry, you can use inheritance or polymorphism.

**To use inheritance, looks like something below:**

```
class Fruit {
  var name: String {
    get {
      return "Fruit"
    }
  }
}

class Orange: Fruit {
  override var name: String {
    get {
      return "Orange"
    }
  }
}

class BlueBerry: Fruit {
  override var name: String {
    get {
      return "BlueBerry"
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Debug Hint

After you updated the code, saying that table view is empty, and cannot find where the problem is. Here is a list of hints I can give you that might be helpful to find your problem.

1. add a breakpoint to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`, see if it breaks.
2. If it breaks, see the array of fruit, is the size of array 0?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Are you able to share what the full code should be for the Table View Controller and Fruit class? I tried to implement your suggestion but my Table View Controller comes up blank.

Comment: @swifty1990 can you show me your code so that I can know why your table view controller comes up blank?

Comment: yes sure! I've added the code for the Table View Controller & the Orange class to my original question. Let me know if there's any others I can add that would be helpful...

Comment: @swifty1990 updated answers with some hints that might help you find the issue.